# Grails Multi-Project: Running a Plugin's custom script

Tags: grails, multi-project

Followed the [tutorial on multi-projects](http://guides.grails.org/grails-multi-project-build/guide/index.html)

Everything mostly works. Plugin controllers & domain classes load properly in the application. However, a problem occurs when trying to run a Plugin's custom script from the application's grails CLI.

For example:

If you set up the multi-project directory structure like this:

- Project Root

  - Application Directory
  - Plugin Directory
  - settings.gradle

And ran this command from the Plugin Directory

```
grails create-script hello
```

You'd be able to access the script when running grails from the Plugin Directory, but not the Application's Directory.

Is there a way to get this to work properly? Do I need to use an alternative set up?

Also see [Creating a Custom Script in Grails](https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Command%20Line/create-script.html)

Comment: After reading more I've come to realize that a multi-project's plugin is different than a conventional grails 3 pluign. For this reason, you want to manually package these plugins.

Answer (score 0):

A conventional grails 3 plugin is different than a plugin within a multi-project. It doesn't seem to be designed to compile a plugin such as grails scaffolding with custom commands.

For this reason, you should package the plugin manually using:

```
grails package-plugin
grails install
```

Now in the build.gradle, add this line to dependencies:

```
compile "<plugin-group>:<plugin-name>:<plugin-version>
```

Subsituting the appropriate information within the brackets <>.

- You can find the plugin-group in the plugin's build.gradle

  - `group "org.grails.plugins"`
- plugin-name you specified in the grails create-plugin command

  - `grails create-plugin plugin-name`
- plugin-version is also found in the plugin's build.gradle

  - `version "0.1"`